# pushSharpでArgumentExceptionが発生します。

Tags: ios, c#, visual-studio, push-notification

Visual Studio 2013のC#で開発しております。

PushSharpを利用してIOSのプッシュサーバを作成しておりますが、
appleSettings = new PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "xxxxxxx");
でArgumentExceptionが発生しております。
何が原因でどうしたら解決できるのか教えてください。

エラー発生時のスクリーンショットです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下は自分のコードです。

```
private static PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings appleSettings = null;
private static PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings GetAppleSettingsDebug()
{
    if (appleSettings == null)
    {
        // TODO : 設定値
        var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\APNs\development.p12");
        appleSettings = new PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "xxxxxxx");
    }
    return appleSettings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

追加情報の英語のメッセージを読んでください。

本番用の「Production Certificate」を作成し、そちらを使う必要があります。確認して下さい。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/samril/20130902/1378198909

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
本番用の「Production Certificate」はすでにあります。ですが、本番用を使っても同じエラーが出ます。追加情報のメッセージは「You have selected the Development/Sandbox (Not production) server, yet your Certificate does not appear to be the Development/Sandbox certificate!  Please check to ensure you have the correct certificate!」のように出てます。